# PostgreSQL - create a new DB through pgAdmin UI

Tags: postgresql, user-interface, pgadmin

I have installed PostgreSQL DB server on my Ubuntu machine. Now I want to create a new Database through some GUI application. I tried pgAdmin but didn't find any option to create a new DB. But I could add existing db servers.

Is there any way to create a DB and then tables through pgAdmin or some other app.

Basically I am looking for an application for PostgreSQL like [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) for MySQL.

Answer (score 29):

1. Open pgAdmin
2. Connect to database server
3. Edit => New Object => New database
4. done

Or use plain SQL when connection to any database: `CREATE DATABASE my_database;`

Comment: what if "New Object" is greyed out?

Comment: On some systems createdb my_database is the correct syntax.

Comment: if the "New Object" is greyed out, login as the database admin

Comment: pgAdmin has default admin account, which is name: "postgres". To create a new database, just open "login/group role", update password of "postgres" user, then login again with it. The "Database..." option will be enable.

Comment: @BrianVo What you said, thanks! Seems like the create database menu option is not allowed unless a password has been set for the admin user (named postgres in PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 16):

*HI ... Verify that u have done above steps to install the postgresql properly ... and follow the below instructions to create a database in POSTGRESQL*

**INSTALL POSTGRESQL**

1.Install latest PostgreSQL 9.1 in console:

`sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev`

2.PostgreSQL has a super user is called postgres. Change user to the PostgreSQL user:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

3.Change password of postgres user:

```
psql -d postgres -U postgres
```

psql (9.1.3) Type "help" for help

```
    postgres=# alter user postgres with password 'YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD';
    ALTER ROLE
    postgres=# \q
    #logout postgres user
    logout
```

4.Restart the PostgreSQL server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

pgAdmin III: PostgreSQL administration and management tools

If pgAdminIII is not installed, the installation is easy:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

**ADD A SEVER**

Open pgAdminIII and add new localhost server. Go to menu File > Add Server

Set up pgAdmin III server instrumentation:

When connecting to a PostgreSQL database using pgAdmin you may receive an error letting you know that the server instrumentation is not installed.

Install postgresql-contrib package:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

Install adminpack extension:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION "adminpack";
postgres=# \q
```

**CREATE DATABASE**

1.Double Click your database in Left pane on PGAdmin to select it

2.Now click the a Icon named "SQL" ,probably 6th icon, and type CREATE table query in resultant window

***EXAMPLE:***

3.Create table query

```
CREATE TABLE explore(
SUBJECT  TEXT     NOT NULL,
COMPANY  CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PNAME    TEXT     NOT NULL,
PHONE    INT      NOT NULL,
EMAIL    CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
REMARKS  CHAR(200) NOT NULL
);
```

Post any queries below.............Have a error free day.

Answer (score 3):

One of problems with DB creating is connected to permissions.

If there are no grant for creating database, the path "Object -> Create -> Database" is off (unclickable) and you can't pick this menu option. Likewise, "Databases -> Right Mouse Button" doesn't have "Create" option. One more sign of this case is the reaction in SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE DBNAME; 

ERROR:  permission denied to create database
********** Error **********
```

To solve the problem you can reconnect to the Server with the first login ('postgres' for example). And afterwards the menu will work.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can create a database with pgAdmin.

You have to understand the basic concept of PostgreSQL. First you have to connect to a **database cluster**, which you can only do by connecting to a database in that cluster. Now, if your database does not exist, yet, there is the default maintenance db **`postgres`** you can connect to. Connect to it and issue `CREATE DATABASE` there. Then change to the new database.

Answer (score 1):

On windows right click on the db connector

[image]

My db connector is PostgreSQL->Create->Database, expand the database
[image]

Next expand schema
[image]

under which tables is found, then right click, and create tables

To create tables Expand database->under that expand schema->under tables , click on create tables


To add columns and data types to tables
under the respective table, right click properties and select column fields and add name of columns, data types as needed
 properties->columns
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm late to the party, but it seems that regular old [PG_Admin](https://www.pgadmin.org/), and the [EnterpriseDB installation](https://www.enterprisedb.com/) are different packages. PG_Admin by itself just manages and connects to servers, but doesn't seem to create them. This is definitely not clear, but yeah you get those errors because you're trying to connect to a server that doesn't exist. You could also use WSL to do this, but you'd have to have WSL and your server up and running everytime to you play.